# How to click on a button till page title change using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop, automated-tests

I have one button which sometimes does not do the actual click, due to that i wrote a code to handle it with a while loop where it will click until it finds out a new assignment title of the page. But this is not working as expected. Please help me, thanks in advance.

```
    String titleWhenLoad = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='assignment_title']")).getText();

    String titleNext = titleWhenLoad;
    while ((titleWhenLoad.equals(titleNext))
            && (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='assignment_title']")).isDisplayed())) {

        WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]"))
        btn.click();
        
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='assignment_title']")).isDisplayed()) {
            titleNext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='assignment_title']")).getText();

        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: i strongly suggest the usage of waits ( https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html ) rather than using a loop. It would loop thousands of time every second, which is not efficent

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar I tried using them, but sometimes the button is not clicking actually. Even i tried with java script it's not working in either way. This button is common through out the application and due to this my scripts are failing.

Comment: @frainH has answered below, combining both loops and wait. Since it will loop only once in 3 seconds, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebDriverWait` utilizing `.invisibilityOfElementWithText` to wait a element with specific text disappear.

To click the button target, I suggest to use `Actions` class.

Check it out:

```
String titleWhenLoad = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='assignment_title']")).getText();

boolean findNewTitle = false;
while (!findNewTitle) {
    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(By.xpath("//span[@class='assignment_title']"), titleWhenLoad));
        findNewTitle = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.moveToElement(btn).click(btn).build().perform();
    }
}
```

Import the following:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Reference:

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#expected-conditions

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

Comment: This works like a charm. You saved my time. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cindy87 Welcome, Glad to hear it.